# Using A variable to Index

Tags: python, list, variables

My current problem is I want to search for items in a list but only for the number of items in said list

```
drumsound = ["0"]
def AddSnare():
  drumsound.append("1")
  print(drumsound)
  
def AddTom():
  drumsound.append("2")
  print(drumsound)

def beat(): 
  a = 1
  for x in drumsound:
   if drumsound[a] == "1":
    mixer.music.load("soundfiles/snare.mp3")
    mixer.music.set_volume(1)
    mixer.music.play()
    a += 1
   
   elif drumsound[a] == "2":
     mixer.music.load("soundfiles/tom.mp3")
     mixer.music.set_volume(1)
     mixer.music.play()
     a += 1
```

My problem is if in this line `if drumsound[a] == "1":` i can use `[a]`as a variable or a way i can do something simmaler

Comment: Your post doesn't make your question clear

Comment: and please try to put the whole code so that we can copy-paste and check it in our devices.

Comment: Instead of `b-1` use `b -= 1`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be the substraction that you are doing to the `b` variable in both conditions:

```
b = len(drumsound)
  a = 0
  while b > 0:
   if drumsound[a] == "1":
    mixer.music.load("soundfiles/snare.mp3")
    mixer.music.set_volume(1)
    mixer.music.play()
    b -= 1
    a += 1
   
   elif drumsound[a] == "2":
     mixer.music.load("soundfiles/tom.mp3")
     mixer.music.set_volume(1)
     mixer.music.play()
     b -= 1
     a += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code was addressed by [@U12-Forward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69805884/using-a-variable-to-index#comment123391163_69805884) in the comments. I just want to show how you can do the same in more pythonic way

```
drum_sounds = '122112'
files = {'1':"soundfiles/snare.mp3", '2':"soundfiles/tom.mp3"}
for tone in drum_sounds:
    mixer.music.load(files[tone])
    mixer.music.set_volume(1)
    mixer.music.play()
```